# call function when onclick <a> , then increase count by one, update the change to database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

The div's content are generated by the database ordered by "cts"(a count number). when I click the div, I want the "cts" number to increase by one, and then the change is updated to the database. as a result, the content will change accordingly. 
AJAX:

```
function addcount()
{
    console.log('step1');
    var id=this.rowid; 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        console.log('step2');
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        console.log('step3');
            document.getElementById("cts").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","addcount.php?q="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

php CODE:

```
<?php 
require_once "db.php";
session_start();
$id=intval($_GET['id'])
$sql="UPDATE words SET cts=cts+1 WHERE id='$id'";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
?>
```

-------This does not work at all-------Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not `jQuery` and `jQuery.Ajax` ? Check this out: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Your question is tagged `jquery`, but I don't see you using jQuery anywhere in your code. Are you actually using it?

Comment: Programming business is simple nowadays. 1. Pile up some random lines of code. 2.Find it doesn't work. 3. Post it on Stack Overflow to let someone sort it out for you. 4.??? 5. PROFIT!!!

Comment: Side note: Your code falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), because you don't declare `xmlhttp` in your `addcount` function. Always declare your variables.

Comment: Have you tried building it without Javascript/Ajax? That might be easier to debug (just a normal link with a page refresh). And when that works, it should be trivial to add Ajax. And besides, if that goes wrong, then you know where to look, because the server side part was already okay.

Comment: what value to you get in `$_GET`

Comment: I removed the `jquery` tag.

Answer (score 1):

`?q="+id` and `$_GET['id']`.

You need to use the same name for your query string parameter throughout.

Change `?q="+id` to `?id="+id` or `$_GET['id']` to `$_GET['q']`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain exactly what your problem is, but one you have is that you're setting `onreadystatechange` before calling `open()`. `open` resets the `XMLHttpRequest` object, so your callback won't ever execute, even if server-side the applications works fine.

Change the order to:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","addcount.php?q="id,true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    console.log('step3');
        document.getElementById("cts").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem I'm having is like Quentin said:keep id and p identical. so I changed `?q="+id to ?id="+id`

the other problem I'm having is $(this).rowid does not refers to the exact value I want. Therefore, I used parameter to solve this problem.

it's now working rather well. Thanks you all for you help.
html

```
onclick="addcount('.htmlentities($row['id']).');return false;"
```

ajax:

```
function addcount(id)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","addcount.php?id="+id,true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      console.log(xmlhttp);
    document.getElementById("cts").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    else{
      console.log(xmlhttp.readystatus);
      console.log(xmlhttp.status);
    }
  }
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

php:

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
require_once "db.php";
session_start();
$id=intval($_GET['id']);
$sql="UPDATE words SET cts=cts+1 WHERE id='$id'";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
?>
```

Thank you:)